# dropping unnecessary text from list of string

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

Existing Df :

```
Id                                            dates
01         ['ATIVE 04/2018 to 03/2020',' XYZ mar 2020 – Jul 2022','June 2021 - 2023 XYZ']
```

Expected Df :

```
Id                                            dates
01         ['04/2018 to 03/2020','mar 2020 – Jul 2022','June 2021 - 2023']
```

I am looking to clean the List under the dates column. i tried it with below function but doesn't serve the purpose. Any leads on the same..?

```
def clean_dates_list(dates_list):
    cleaned_dates_list = []
    for date_str in dates_list:
        cleaned_date_str = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z\s\d]+', '', date_str)
        cleaned_dates_list.append(cleaned_date_str)
    return cleaned_dates_list
```

Comment: Regex has no notion of "unnecessary text". You must define it, please provide criteria to either remove or keep specific patterns.

Comment: i just wanted to remove the unnecessary words except month and year

Comment: But `mar`, `to`, `June` is not `month` and `year`. `[^A-Za-z\s\d]+` is not an attempt to match that either. Dates can come in many formats, and you even have ranges here.

Comment: i have the data in these format. mar stands for march and like wise

Comment: How do you call the code? Can you construct the DF instead of providing a visual representation?

Answer (score 2):

```
ls = ['ATIVE 04/2018 to 03/2020', ' XYZ mar 2020 – Jul 2022', 'June 2021 - 2023 XYZ']

ls_to_remove = ['ATIVE', 'XYZ']

for item in ls:
    ls_str = item.split()
    new_item = str()
    for item in ls_str:
        if item in ls_to_remove:
            continue
        new_item += " " + item
    print(new_item)
```

I don't know your list of words to remove and it's not a good practice. But in your case it works.